# Sum over spatialGridDataFrame: rowSums or colSums

Tags: r, sum

I want to do simple operation on a spatial grid data frame. Consider I need to know the sum of each columns for each spatial points(herein row). Unfortunately I couldn't do that using sum or rowSums function. Could you please help me how to do that? I've searched a lot but really didn't see any similar case.

My data summary is:

```
 FLint
 Object of class SpatialGridDataFrame
Object of class SpatialGrid
Grid topology:
  cellcentre.offset cellsize cells.dim
x          582228.8 9.071439       568
y         4505538.0 9.071439       445
SpatialPoints:
                 x       y
     [1,] 582228.8 4509566
     [2,] 582237.9 4509566
     ....
  Data summary:
 Deterministic        sim001           sim002                   
 Min.   :1        Min.   :1        Min.   :1               
 1st Qu.:1        1st Qu.:1        1st Qu.:1             
 Median :1        Median :1        Median :1               
 Mean   :1        Mean   :1        Mean   :1               
 3rd Qu.:1        3rd Qu.:1        3rd Qu.:1              
 Max.   :1        Max.   :1        Max.   :1               
 NA's   :220354   NA's   :220354   NA's   :220354
```

Here I tried a lot to sum for example two last column:

```
y2 <- rowSums (FLint[,2:3], na.rm = TRUE, dims = 1)
Error in base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm slightly confused as to whether you want `rowSums()` or `colSums()`, but both will be used in the same way:

You need to call `rowSums()` over the `data` slot of the S4 object

Here's a toy example

```
library(sp)

## data taken from ?SpatialGridDataFrame
data(meuse.grid) # only the non-missing valued cells
coordinates(meuse.grid) = c("x", "y") # promote to SpatialPointsDataFrame
gridded(meuse.grid) <- TRUE # promote to SpatialPixelsDataFrame
x = as(meuse.grid, "SpatialGridDataFrame")

## the data is contained in '@data'
rowSums(x@data[, c("part.a", "part.b")], na.rm = T)
```

So in your example I *think* you'll want

```
rowSums(Flint@data[, 2:3])
```

---

You can see where the data is if you look at the structure

```
str(x)
Formal class 'SpatialGridDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 4 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 8112 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ part.a: num [1:8112] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ part.b: num [1:8112] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ dist  : num [1:8112] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ soil  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ ffreq : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..@ grid       :Formal class 'GridTopology' [package "sp"] with 3 slots
  .. .. ..@ cellcentre.offset: Named num [1:2] 178460 329620
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. .. ..@ cellsize         : Named num [1:2] 40 40
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. .. ..@ cells.dim        : Named int [1:2] 78 104
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 178440 329600 181560 333760
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
```

Comment: Thank you brother. The only thing that I missed for several hours of confusing was 'data'. I'm new to this language and couldn't understand after a lot of searching.

Comment: @Mohammad You're welcome. It would be worth understanding the difference between `S3` and `S4` objects in R. I would say 99% of the time you'll be working with `S3`, but these spatial objects are all `S4`.

Comment: @Mohammad - and if this answers your question you can 'accept' it by pressing the 'tick' under the voting arrows.

Comment: I made some changes on my code and again received the error: `Error in ncol(xj) : object 'xj' not found`.What's the problem? My code is: `FLintMod[[2+nsim]] <- rowSums(FLintMod@data[, 2:(1+nsim)], na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @SymbolixAU- Please See the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122894/error-in-ncolxj-object-xj-not-found-using-rowsums?noredirect=1&lq=1)