# Error in ncol(xj) : object 'xj' not found using rowSums

Tags: r, raster, rowsum

I'm using R and rowSums function for a data frame as discussed in this post: [Sum over spatialGridDataFrame: rowSums or colSums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047885/sum-over-spatialgriddataframe-rowsums-or-colsums). Now suing rowSums as follows:

```
FLintMod[[2+nsim]] <- rowSums(FLintMod@data[, 2:(1+nsim)], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Now I'm facing new error and I really don't have any idea why I'm getting this error:

```
Error in ncol(xj) : object 'xj' not found
```

Could you please help me understand this problem and solve it.

For your information, this code worked before but after improving code and specially  doing the following work to return raster to spatial grid data frame I got this error:

```
FLintRaster <- raster(FLint[i+1])
FLintRasterMod <- mask(FLintRaster, FloodExtent)
FLintMod[[i+1]] <- as(FLintRasterMod,"SpatialGridDataFrame")@data
```

Best,

Comment: @SymbolixAU Can you help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found my answer. I generated data frame @ data frame! In oredr to return raster to data frame I should use as.vector() function.

```
FLintRaster <- raster(FLint[i+1])
FLintRasterMod <- mask(FLintRaster, FloodExtent)   
FLintMod[[i+1]] <- as.vector(FLintRasterMod, mode='any')
```

I'll be happy if someone can explain more technically what happened in my case. I'm very new to R and eager to learn the basics of that.

Best,